# I am using SAScii package in R to handle a very large file (2.3 gig DAT file). First time recieving current progress message and I am curious

Tags: r, sas

This is my code:

```
library(SAScii)
parse.SAScii("16crime.sas", beginline = 14)
x <- read.SAScii("opafy16nid.dat", "16crime.sas", beginline = 14)
```

It has been running for an hour or so and i got a message reading, "current progress: read.fwf has read in 1,000 records". While this is the largest data ive ever played with, I have never seen this message before. Is this a sign that all is going well?

Comment: So, I do not work in SAS but I read a 20Gig file into R once from SAS using a different method, but it probably was similar under the hood. It had to run overnight....but once it was in and I saved it to an RData document it loaded in less than a minute. My feeling is that it is working line-by-line and holding the resulting data in memory, so depending on how much RAM you have it is probably working fine...if you are on a PC you can use task manager to see if it is actively working the CPU and if memory is maxed out but changing a bit...that is a sign that you are OK.